# In Express.js req.cookies() doesn't working outside of the localhost (Render.com)

Tags: express, cookies, cors, netlify, render.com

I am building a simple e-commerce type webapp. For authentication I used **JWT**. And want to store the token in the cookie as **httpOnly** cookie. Then in ther server-side I am reading it with `req.cookies.auth` using `cookie-parser` package. It working perfectly fine in the **localhost**. I ran the client in **localhost:3000** and the server in **localhost:8080**. But whenever I shifted to **client -> Netlify.app** and **server -> Render.com** or **Railway.app** the cookie is not setting anymore. I still able to set the client side cookies with **document.cookie** to **Netlify**, but server cannot read any cookies **(normal and httpOnly both)**.

Don't know what I'm missing. Please help me guys. It's been 2 days, I'm stucked for it.

Here, my client side code, where I am using redux-toolkit-query:

```
import { createApi, fetchBaseQuery } from "@reduxjs/toolkit/query/react";

export const apiSlice = createApi({
    reducerPath: "api", // optional
    baseQuery: fetchBaseQuery({
        // baseUrl: "http://localhost:8080/api",
        baseUrl: "https://demo.onrender.com/api",
        credentials: "include",
    }),
    tagTypes: ["User", "Medicine", "Gallery", "HealthTip", "Profile"],
    endpoints: (builder) => ({}),
});
```

In server-side: I also includes the cors to the middlewarese:

```
const express = require("express");
const cors = require("cors");
const cookieParser = require("cookie-parser");

const middlewares = [
    cookieParser(),
    cors({
        credentials: true,
        origin: [
            "http://localhost:3000",
            "https://myapp.netlify.app",
        ],
    }),
    express.static("public"),
    express.json({ limit: "500mb" }),
    express.urlencoded({ extended: true, limit: "500mb" }),
];

module.exports = (app) => {
    app.use(middlewares);
};
```

Then set the token like this after successfully login:

```
res.cookie("auth", token, {
    httpOnly: true,
    maxAge: 6 * 60 * 60 * 1000,
});
```

And finally: this is how I am verifying the token:

```
const jwtController = require("../controllers/jwtController");

exports.verifyJWT = (req, res, next) => {
    const token = req.headers?.authorization || req.cookies?.auth;
        console.log(req.headers);

    if (token) {
        if (token.includes("Bearer")) {
            const onlyToken = token.slice(7, token.length);
            req.decoded = jwtController.verifyToken(onlyToken);
            next();
        } else {
            req.decoded = jwtController.verifyToken(token);
            next();
        }
    } else {
        res.status(401).json({
            code: 401,
            message: "Unauthorized request",
        });
    }
};
```

My header response from the console **Render.com** log: (no cookies receiving)

```
{
Apr 7 11:09:57 PM    host: 'demo.onrender.com"',
Apr 7 11:09:57 PM    'user-agent': 'Mozilla/5.0 (Windows NT 10.0; Win64; x64) AppleWebKit/537.36 (KHTML, like Gecko) Chrome/112.0.0.0 Safari/537.36',
Apr 7 11:09:57 PM    accept: '*/*',
Apr 7 11:09:57 PM    'accept-encoding': 'gzip',
Apr 7 11:09:57 PM    'accept-language': 'en-US,en;q=0.6',
Apr 7 11:09:57 PM    'cdn-loop': 'cloudflare; subreqs=1',
Apr 7 11:09:57 PM    'cf-connecting-ip': '103.129.214.72',
Apr 7 11:09:57 PM    'cf-ew-via': '15',
Apr 7 11:09:57 PM    'cf-ipcountry': 'BD',
Apr 7 11:09:57 PM    'cf-ray': '7b43e19782e0bc2d-DAC',
Apr 7 11:09:57 PM    'cf-visitor': '{"scheme":"https"}',
Apr 7 11:09:57 PM    'cf-worker': 'onrender.com',
Apr 7 11:09:57 PM    forwarded: 'for=103.129.214.72;proto=https, for=172.68.218.142, for=10.210.130.185',
Apr 7 11:09:57 PM    'k-proxy-request': 'activator',
Apr 7 11:09:57 PM    origin: 'https://myapp.netlify.app/',
Apr 7 11:09:57 PM    priority: 'u=1, i',
Apr 7 11:09:57 PM    referer: 'https://myapp.netlify.app/',
Apr 7 11:09:57 PM    'render-proxy-ttl': '4',
Apr 7 11:09:57 PM    'sec-ch-ua': '"Chromium";v="112", "Brave";v="112", "Not:A-Brand";v="99"',
Apr 7 11:09:57 PM    'sec-ch-ua-mobile': '?0',
Apr 7 11:09:57 PM    'sec-ch-ua-platform': '"Windows"',
Apr 7 11:09:57 PM    'sec-fetch-dest': 'empty',
Apr 7 11:09:57 PM    'sec-fetch-mode': 'cors',
Apr 7 11:09:57 PM    'sec-fetch-site': 'cross-site',
Apr 7 11:09:57 PM    'sec-gpc': '1',
Apr 7 11:09:57 PM    'true-client-ip': '103.129.214.72',
Apr 7 11:09:57 PM    'x-forwarded-for': '103.129.214.72, 172.68.218.142, 10.210.130.185, 10.210.117.178',
Apr 7 11:09:57 PM    'x-forwarded-proto': 'https',
Apr 7 11:09:57 PM    'x-request-start': '1680887397067980'
Apr 7 11:09:57 PM  }
```